# AWS Lambda - not uploading to S3 when I publish lambda

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, .net-core, aws-lambda

I have an AWS .NET Core lambda, where I am uploading and image to an S3 bucket.

This works fine in development mode using the test tool, but as soon as I publish, this then times out with no error messages.

Here is my code where I am converting a base64 image to a byte array before trying to upload to S3.

It is getting stuck on upload. I have also tried the `UploadAsync` method which does the same.

```
s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(apiKey, apiSecret, bucketRegion);
var fileTransferUtility = new TransferUtility(s3Client);
var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(body.ImgB64.Split(',')[1]);
using var contents = new MemoryStream(bytes);
fileTransferUtility.Upload(contents, bucketName, filePath + "/" + keyName);
```

I am wondering if it is something to do with the permissions needed to upload an object to the S3 bucket?

I am currently using an IAM user which has write access to the bucket using a key and secret provided by AWS, as mentioned this works fine in dev mode.

I have also given the IAM role used for the lambda S3 full access permission.

[image]

Can anyone help?

Comment: Is your lambda in VPC?

Comment: Not sure, how do I check this?

Comment: A common cause for lambda timeout is often due to placing it in VPC. If you haven't explicitly done that, then it is probably not in VPC. You can check it in AWS lambda console. Towards bottom there will be section `VPC`.

Comment: You can check for 2 things - is it in VPC, as suggested above, and check what's you AWS Lambda function timeout (default is 3 seconds, max is 15 minutes)

Comment: I think it is VPN, is there something I need to do in order to fix this.  The timeout has been upped to 30 seconds

Answer (score 0):

Log what is happening - with Lambda you can just print to `stdout` and it will be picked up by CloudWatch logs. After that analyze CloudWatch logs and go from there.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, not sure how you mean though, if it is getting stuck at that place what can I log?